# How to search string in array

Tags: solidity

I have an array.

string[] private NameIndex;

i want to check if the same name is already exist in the array.If same name is exist it will return false and if not exist anf if name is unique it will add the new name in the array and return true.

NameIndex.push("BOB") - 1;

kindly help

Comment: What do you want to achieve by subtracting one?

Comment: 1st entry will go to index 0

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solidity provides no obvious way to do this.

One can contemplate an iterative process to search the list, but the gas cost will increase with the size of the list. This puts an upper bound on the size of the list; either by increasing transaction cost to an unacceptable level, or by exceeding the block gas limit so transactions can't run at all.

There are (at least) two general solutions.

1. **Invert control** so the client performs the iterative operation and interrogates contract functions one row at a time. It's possible to expose indexed lists (searchable) with event emitters. That may help, but in any case, performance will suffer with list size.
2. **Use a mapping** to facilitate random access in a single step.

Since mappings can't be enumerated and it's not possible to know how many keys have been set or what they are, it may be necessary to devise a system of pointers using both arrays and mappings to produce a "list" of randomly accessible items.

Have a look here for a **pattern** and better explanation: https://bitbucket.org/rhitchens2/soliditycrud/overview

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone still wants a solution to identify a string inside an array.

You first need to have a way to compare strings. You can do it using the following function:

```
// Function to compare 2 strings
    function compareStrings(string memory firstString, string memory secondString) internal pure returns (bool) {
      return keccak256(bytes(firstString)) == keccak256(bytes(secondString));
    }
```

This will return `true` if the 2 inputs match.

Then we can use this function to iterate in the array and check if the string exists:

```
function findString(string[] memory array,string memory _string) internal pure returns (bool){
    for (uint i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
        string memory stringToFind = array[i]; 
        bool exists = compareStrings(stringToFind, _string) ;
        if(exists == true) {
            return true;

        }   
    }
        return false;
    }
```

This will return `true` if the string is in the array and `false` if it isn't.

You can then use it like this:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract FindString {

    string[] public colors = ["blue", "yellow", "red"];

    function compareStrings(string memory firstString, string memory secondString) internal pure returns (bool) {
      return keccak256(bytes(firstString)) == keccak256(bytes(secondString));
    }


    function findString(string[] memory array,string memory _string) internal pure returns (bool){
    for (uint i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
        string memory stringToFind = array[i]; 
        bool exists = compareStrings(stringToFind, _string) ;
        if(exists == true) {
            return true;

        }   
    }
        return false;
    }


    function findStringInArray(string memory _string) public view returns(bool){
        return findString(colors, _string);
    }

}
```

I also made a Solidity library to help with these kind of tasks:

- [Soliditool](https://github.com/soos3d/Soliditool-solidity-utils-library)