# Check a user's address when accessing the agreement

Tags: contract-development, contract-design

I am developing a contract where a predetermined address can change a contract variable.

The structure of my current contract is as follows:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract privacyPreferences {

 bool preference = false;                              

function changePreferences() public {
   if (msg.sender == ADDRESS  )
      preference = true;
 }


 function preferenceStatus() public view returns (bool) {
    return preference;
 }
 }
```

In the `changePreferences()` function, I compare the user who is requesting access with the `ADDRESS` variable. The `ADDRESS` variable can have multiple values. In my application several addresses may request access to the contract. My question is: How do I make this validation in the contract considering that the variable `ADDRESS` can have more than one value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```solidity
mapping (address => bool) addresses;

constructor () public {
  addresses [ADDRESS1] = true;
  addresses [ADDRESS2] = true;
  ...
}

function changePreferences () public {
  if (addresses [msg.sender])
    preference = true;
}
```

Comment: What is the function of this line: `mapping (address => bool) addresses;`

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: this solution does not generate a high gas cost?

Comment: Depends on how many addresses do you have.  You may also consider using compressed list of addresses or bloom filter.

Comment: Inside [ADDRESS1] the value needs to be between `" "`?

Comment: No, address literals in Solidity look like `0x0123456789012345678901234567890123456789`.

Answer (score 2):

Solidity doesn't provide features to easily check whether a value is inside an array. Here are some more details: [How to search string in array](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12537/how-to-search-string-in-array)

So basically you have to either iterate over all the array's values every time, change it into a mapping (probably the best idea) or do something else creative. The mapping could be simply `mapping(address => boolean) hasAccess;` where each user with access has a value of `true` (`false` is the default for booleans so everyone else has `false` if checked).

Also you should put your access check in a modifier so it's easier to use. So something like this:

```
modifier canChangePreferences {
   require(access[msg.sender]);
   _;          
}
```